# How can Domain Objects that represent entities like pictures or files in general be handled in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I can't seem to find any examples, or blogs that talk about modeling things that represent files, when file handles don't apply the ubiquitous language. Is it okay to have entities(like Image or Document) in the system that contain a file handle, or am I going about this wrong. Please help

Answer (score 2):

This depends. If an image or a file is a part of your domain (Say you are building some photo app) then it is fine to represent them in your domain. But if a file is just some storage mechanism that you are using, then that should be abstracted away from the domain.

There is no definitive answer as this highly depends on your domain.

I recently ran into the same issue with emails. Say you have the following rule:

> Send user an email upon registration

Say you have also decided that the email queue will be stored in the same database as your domain. It would seem fine to have the concept of an email as part of your domain. But you have to ask yourself the following questions.

- What if I want to send a text along with an email?
- What if you decide to use an emailing service that you don't manage?

In both these cases you have to make direct changes to the domain.

A better approach will be to add an infrastructure layer. In your domain you will have an interface like `IUserNotifier` and you will then implement this interface in your infrastructure layer. Sudo domain code can look something like this:

```
IUserNotifier.NotifyOfRegistration(newUser)
```

Now you can easily implement the notifier to either send an email, or a text or call a 3rd party service or whatever. Your domain is non the wiser and requires no change.

I know my example does not directly answer your question, but gives you some guidelines as to how to think about things.

This is the thing about domain driven design. It is completely centered around the domain thus making each case unique.

Answer (score 1):

File handles typically would not be part of most domains simply because they are on an infrastructure level.  If you are building something related to the infrastructure level then it would be perfectly fine.

If you have business concepts like your `Image` or `Document` the you *may* include a file handle or path of sorts in there if you are tied to the infrastructure.  However, you could also opt for something more generic like a `Descriptor` or `Uri`.  Perhaps some documents are file-based and others are stored in a content-engine.  You could have something like this:

`file://c:/somewhere/some-file.txt`

`content://my-server/some-content-id`

Then to get to, say, a `Stream` to return the real, physical, content you could have some service to fetch the stream based on the scheme/descriptor.

But there would be options depending on what you are comfortable with. :)